# Implementing fluent generic class methods Typescript

Tags: typescript, class, generics, methods, fluent

How does one implement a fluent (chainable) generic map function on a collection class? Consider the below:

```js
class Array_<T> {
    private _arr: T[]

    constructor(iterable: Iterable<T>) { this._arr = [...iterable] }

    [Symbol.iterator]() { return this._arr[Symbol.iterator]() }

    map<Y>(projector: (item: T) => Y): Array_<Y> {
        return new Array_((function* (iterable: Iterable<T>) {
            for (const element of iterable) {
                yield projector(element)
            }
        })(this))
    }
}

class ArrayCustom<T> extends Array<T> { }

let mappedArr = new ArrayCustom([1,2,3]).map(element=>element.toString())
```

The inferred type of `mappedArr` is `Array_<string>`, but I want it to be `ArrayCustom<string>`

Comment: Using the name `Array` is unfortunate, as there is generally already an array constructor in scope with the name `Array`.  And in TypeScript, the type `Array<T>` is already the same as `T[]`.  This is at best confusing (if you are shadowing names in your own module or namespace) and at worst an error (if you try to do this in global scope).  Consider changing it.

Comment: @jcalz This is just for illustrative purposes; I do not use the name `Array` in my code

Comment: Unless you are trying to illustrate shadowing or name collisions I'd suggest you change it in the question code... note how the answer below had to change it to something else (`AppArray`) in order for the answer to compile properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to redefine `map` in `ArrayCustom`:

```
class ArrayCustom<T> extends AppArray<T> {
  map<Y>(projector: (item: T) => Y): ArrayCustom<Y> {
    return super.map(projector)
  }
}

// let mappedArr: ArrayCustom<string>
let mappedArr = new ArrayCustom([1, 2, 3]).map(element => element.toString());
```

PS: I changed your `Array` to `AppArray` - I got a duplicate type compile error with Array, because it already exists as global type.

You cannot use [Polymorphic this types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types), as you return a new object in `map` for the fluent interface every time. That would require the object to be the same. Also it is not possible to parametrize the returned array type, as TypeScript does not support [higher kinded generic types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) (see comment by jcalz).

Side note:
If you want to do a shallow clone of the array, map all items and do not rely on the async generator, you may implement `map` easier with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
map2<Y>(projector: (item: T) => Y): AppArray<Y> {
  return new AppArray(Array.from(this, projector));
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#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-JrZJKGIAOa4IiFz2IeilxwuSVwMMWquKLgARk1DM1AGYeMYU40sUCQf8xgDZ6DbPJglIKPWkvigA)

Comment: This answer looks right... just to add more detail, the reason this can't be done without some manual step like overriding the subclass methods is because TypeScript does not have [higher kinded generic types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) where a type parameter can itself take a type parameter.  So there's no way to have a generic like `A extends MyArray` and then use `A<T>`.

Comment: @jcalz thank you, very informative! I'll add that link to the answer, if you don't mind.